# React-navigation reset function is not passing parameter

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

Someone now how to pass parameters effectively with navigation.reset() function?

I have tried to pass parameters to the [react-navigation reset function](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/#reset) but got always undefined so far

First try:

```
import {CommonActions} from '@react-navigation/native';

navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    routes: [
      {
        name: 'ConnectionStack',
        params: {zob: 'zob'},
      },
    ],
  }),
);
```

Second try:

```
const MyComponent = ({navigation}) => {
    navigation.reset({
        index: 0,
        routes: [{name: 'ConnectionStack', params: {zob: 'zob'}}],
      });
  };
```

params are always undefined but my navigation is reset like I want.

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution?

Comment: also looking for solution